# Android Local KML File & Google Maps

Tags: android, android-intent, maps, kml

I am trying to write and then load a KML file using Google Maps via an Intent.  I have tried both internal and external storage for the KML file - it seems to be writing correctly, but I keep getting the following error Toast in Google Maps:

No results found for:file:///data/data/[my app package path]/kml_to_view.kml

### Writing To File

```
File dir = context.getFilesDir();
//File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Log.d(TAG, "Writing to dir: " + dir);
File kmlFile = new File(dir, KML_FILE_NAME);
FileOutputStream fos;
try 
{
    kmlFile.createNewFile();
    fos = context.openFileOutput(KML_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    //fos = new FileOutputStream(kmlFile);
    fos.write(kmlData.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    isKMLPrepared = true;
    Toast.makeText(context, "file write successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you can see I have the pieces necessary to write either to internal storage or external and I have tried both.

### Sending KML To Maps

```
File dir = context.getFilesDir();
Log.d(TAG, "Local file path: " + dir);
readInternalStoragePrivate(KML_FILE_NAME);          

mapsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);//Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps"));
//String uri = "geo:0,0?q=file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + KML_FILE_NAME;
String uri = "geo:0,0?q=file://" + context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + KML_FILE_NAME;
Log.d(TAG, "URI: " + uri);
mapsIntent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
```

Again I have tried reading both internal and external locations when sending a path to the Maps app.

Any idea what I need to do to get the Maps app to read and process a locally stored KML file?  I have read a number of other posts, but I have yet to find a solution to my problem.